# Kendo Grid not binding to JSON result from ASMX Web Service

Tags: asp.net, json, kendo-grid, asmx

I have a problem binding Kendo GRID to ASP.NET asmx web service.

Following is HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../BOOTSTRAP/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../BOOTSTRAP/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="example">
        <div id="grid" class="table table-bordered"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    columns: [
            { field: "srno", title: "SRNO" },
            { field: "party", title: "PARTY" }
                    ],
                    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "../Service/DatabaseHandling.asmx/GetPurchaseJangad_JSON",
                                dataType: "json",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                    schema: {
                        data: "d"

                    },
                    sortable: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JSON returned from service is looking ok as below.

```
{"d":"[{\"srno\":17,\"party\":\"PARESH\",\"dt\":\"11/5/2015\",\"weight\":15000.0,\"timestamp\":\"2015-05-11T20:19:55.093\"},{\"srno\":18,\"party\":\"SIM\",\"dt\":\"11/5/2015\",\"weight\":11000.0,\"timestamp\":\"2015-05-11T20:21:44.177\"}]"}
```

Still nothing is visible on GRID.
And no error in browser console.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I know, but the result JSON does not have any problem, so why grid is not binding?@JohnSaunders

Comment: Something like this might help, but its not using MVC.http://stackoverflow.com/a/30183044/2270492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the JSON data only.

Modified JSON given below, replaced \" with " and removed the quote just before and after the square brackets

```
{"d":[{"srno":17,"party":"PARESH","dt":"11/5/2015","weight":15000.0,"timestamp":"2015-05-11T20:19:55.093"},{"srno":18,"party":"SIM","dt":"11/5/2015","weight":11000.0,"timestamp":"2015-05-11T20:21:44.177"}]}
```

[Please find the fiddle here after cleaning up the json](http://dojo.telerik.com/ObuZe)

Comment: Great, the returned JSON is from asmx service. Can you tell me how do i remove quote and backslash-quote at asmx level?

Comment: Your reply helped me a lot. I didnt find anything on server side to remove those extra quotes. But I did it on client side after an ajax call. Then i passed that data to Kendo GRID. And it worked fine. I am posting solution now.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the jQuery code to following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data;
        var webMethod = "../Service/DatabaseHandling.asmx/GetPurchaseJangad_JSON";
        var parameters = "{}";
        $.ajax({

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: webMethod,
            data: parameters,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                data = $.parseJSON(response.d);
                console.log(data);
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    columns: [
            { field: "srno", title: "SRNO" },
            { field: "party", title: "PARTY" },
            { field: "dt", title: "DATE" },
            { field: "weight", title: "WEIGHT" }
                    ],
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: function (options) {
                                options.success(data);
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

What I did, is called that service via jQuery ajax. Got the data containing backslash and quotes. Then as in code, used $.parseJSON to get the required JSON format. Then passed that data to Kendo GRID after success. And thats how its working for me.

But still I am looking for a way to do this on server side, if possible.

Thanks